# How to mv .bin bin

Tags: linux, mv

I was hiding some of the folders on my Ubuntu machine.  By mistake, I have hidden bin folder too by using

```
cd /
mv bin .bin
```

Now I could cd to .bin, but I am not able to unhide the bin directory.  Can someone help?  I was trying the following command:

```
mv .bin bin
```

I am getting the following error

```
bash: /bin/mv: No such file or directory
```

I tried to login as root, but my machine is asking me to install login.  On doing apt-get install login, I am getting a message login is currently the latest version.

Comment: To help others in similar cases, the first rule is don't panic. Then read below's top answer. But to get even more ideas of what is possible : http://www.lug.wsu.edu/node/414 (different system, different os, but the ideas are still relevant, and unix's reliability is (almost, if distribs remember to keep it sane) still shining)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

If you still have a root shell open, run

```
cd /
/.bin/mv .bin bin
```

Your shell can’t find `mv` because it’s no longer on the path; giving the full path to it will allow it to run.

(As a general rule, it’s best not to rename directories outside of your home directory — they are managed by the package manager, and you are likely to confuse it and prevent updates from being applied in the future.)

Comment: Thank you so much....I thought i s***wed up my machine and started taking backup like a maniac.

Comment: @Apricot No need to panic. Even if you could not have been able to restore the directory names from within your running (and broken) system, you could have still used a live system for rescuing it.

Comment: @Apricot: well, that's good, but backup should be taken *before* something bad happens ;)  Continue taking backups regularly from now on.

Comment: Yes, making backups is always good, even if they turn out to be not necessary for the current situation.

Comment: What happens to `/.bin/mv` itself after executing this command? Is the binary locked while the process is running or will it move itself without complaint?

Comment: @user3490 it moves itself without complaint; see [Overwriting a running executable or .so](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/404551/86440) for details.

Comment: Abstractly, renaming `/.bin` to `/bin` changes neither any file within the renamed directory, nor the directory itself; the only thing that is changed is the name of one entry in the _root_ directory!

Comment: Indeed @zwol, which means `mv` doesn’t actually move itself at all, so my comment above is rather moot.