# Does fork() also copy the file descriptor for the executable binary that the calling process is currently executing?

Tags: kernel, process, file-descriptors, system-calls, fork

I've read the man pages on fork(), and they say something along the lines of "all file descriptors open in the calling process are copied".

It is not 100% clear to me if the file descriptor for the executable binary that the calling process is executing at that point in time is included in that statement.
I know the man pages say "all file descriptors", but I'm asking this because it would seem easier to me to `open()` the same executable binary for the forked process, rather than synchronizing two processes working with them.
So if they are indeed also copied, why?

Comment: A running program doesn't have an open file descriptor associated with the on-disk file that was used to run it.

Comment: THis question is very confused -- it looks as if the poster doesn't undesrstand the technical meaning of "file descriptor" at all.

Comment: @q.undertow can you elaborate how this is a misunderstanding in what a file descriptor technically is?

Comment: @darthDoe : essentially. a file descriptor is a reference to an _already open_ file. So your stated goal of re-opening the executable doesn't make good sense.

Comment: from my understanding it is a reference to a file description, my point was to create a new fildes using the open() syscall instead of copying the existing fildes and therefor using the same file description in both processes. Obviously my basis was flawed, but I don't think that I understand file descriptors incorrectly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no file descriptor to the binary file being executed, only memory mappings.

(See, e.g. `ls -l /proc/self/fd` and `cat /proc/self/maps` on Linux.)

The memory mappings will point to the same file, of course, but that's what happens with shared libraries, too. In the case of the main program file, on Linux, writes to it while it's being used by a running process are not allowed. (Though the last time I checked, that didn't apply to shared libraries.)

Comment: Re the latter point, see [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/404598/86440).

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what you're actually trying to do, but on Linux (and some other systems) you can get a file descriptor to the current executable with `open("/proc/self/exe", ...)`. That will work even if the file was removed or never existed in the filesystem.

Just like `/dev/tty` (which will always open the controlling tty of the calling process -- if any), `/proc/self/exe` will always open the file which the calling process is currently executing. They both act as "doors" to hidded open file descriptions already referenced by the process, allowing them to be accessed like normal files.

Those are hardly the only "hidden"/latent file descriptors a process has. In particular you can create a memory mapping of a file with `mmap(..., fd, ...)`, and then closing `fd` will NOT remove that mapping, and your process will still hold a reference to that file, just like a file descriptor would (and on Linux, you can turn it back into a file descriptor by opening `/proc/self/map_files/<range>`).

---

Other examples are the root and current working directory (`/proc/self/{cwd,root}`) -- though, just as with any directories, even those referenced via open fds, their semantics are different than those of regular files -- in particular, you cannot create a file inside a removed directory, the way you can keep writing data to a removed file via its still opened file descriptor.